# How to add a reply to a comment in a post section in Django

Tags: django

I am trying to add a reply to comments on a post section for a post

I have commented out the reply that I have added in the `views.py` as it is not working at all

The templates are working perfectly but with every new reply comment is added not a reply so the issue is with the views I guess

I have added a reply section to the comment models as following: 
`models.py`

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(
        Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reply = models.ForeignKey(
        'Comment', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="replies")
    content = models.TextField(max_length=160)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} by {}'.format(self.post.title, str(self.user.username))
```

here is the views:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "post_detail.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data()
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(
            post=post, reply=None).order_by('-id')
        total_likes = post.total_likes()
        liked = False
        if post.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True

        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            comment_form = CommentForm(self.request.POST or None)
            if comment_form.is_valid():
                content = self.request.POST.get('content')
                #reply_id = self.request.POST.get('comment_id')
                comment_qs = None

                #if reply_id:
                    #comment_qs = Comment.objects.get(id=reply_id)
                comment = Comment.objects.create(
                    post=post, user=request.user, content=content, reply=comment_qs)
                comment.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect("post_detail.html")
        else:
            comment_form = CommentForm()

        context["total_likes"] = total_likes
        context["liked"] = liked
        context["comments"] = comments
        context["comment_form"] = comment_form
        return context

class PostCommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    form_class = CommentForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.instance.post = post
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('score:post-detail', kwargs=dict(slug=self.kwargs['slug']))
```

Comment: Note that the handling 'POST' block should not be in get_context_data(). you need handle post in post(self,request, *args,**kwargs).

Comment: @Blackdoor how should I fix it in the get_context_data()? Do I need to add a function or a class for the reply separately?

Comment: try droping the POST block in get_context_data(), and path the comment post url to the PostCommentCreateView.Normally, it works as your mind, if need, you can handle post in PostCommentCreateView.

Comment: @Blackdoor if you could clarify it in as an answer I would highly appreciate it